# What does the registry number of The Orville (ECV-197) mean?

Tags: the-orville

What is the origin of The Orville's registry number, ECV-197? It can be seen on the side of the ship in the opening animations. What does "ECV" stand for in-universe, and why was this particular number chosen?

Address both in and out-of-universe reasons for the name, if possible. (for example does "197" have some meaning to the writers of the show)

<sup>As a side note, I noticed that the shuttlecraft carry the same registry number with a suffix. We've seen at least ECV-197-1 and ECV-197-2 so far.</sup>

Comment: Somewhat related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92275/is-there-any-out-of-universe-meaning-to-starship-registry-numbers

Comment: No idea if it's related, but "E Clampus Vitus" (ECV) is a drinking society known for pranks and practical jokes. AFAIK it's kind of like a blue collar fraternity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would appear that the prefix ECV stands for **Exploratory-Class Vessel**.

---

In Season 1, Episode 6 we encounter the USS Olympia. Its prefix is **L**CV-529 and is described by Seth Macfarlane as a "[Leviathan class](https://twitter.com/SethMacFarlane/status/918644989487341569)"

[image]

And in the Orville comic [New Beginnings, Pt. 1](https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/New_Beginnings,_Pt._1) we encounter the **B**CV Burton. It's described as a battleship.

[image]

In the opening episode the Orville is described as an "*exploratory vessel"*.

> *"The USS Orville. It's not exactly a heavy cruiser, but it is an exploratory vessel."*

Which gives us L for Leviathan, B for Battleship, E for Exploratory, C for Class and V for Vessel.

---

There are no indications what the numbers refer to, but it can be surmised that it's a build number, 001 potentially being the first in its class.

Comment: Note to self: Never board a vessel with build #001...

Comment: I imagine #013 (or #004 for Eastern cultures) would also be considered trouble.

Comment: Always wait for at least `001-SP1`.

Comment: @JRaef - The prototype model always has the best features, like the Sony camera with the x-ray specs

Comment: @JRaef There's the old joke about never buying a car made on a Friday or a Monday.

Answer (score -1):

As with many things Orville, it can trace back to Star Trek.

There NCC-1701 was arbitrary. Matt Jefferies was an Aviation designer and N is the typical prefix for aircraft registries. The CC1701 was just a choice. Some sorces retcon NCC to mean "Navigation Contact Code" but they are non-canonical.

ECV probably is Exploration Class Vessel, but I don't recall it being explicitly stated.

As to a shuttle being ECV-197-1 that calls back to Enterprise's Shuttles on Star Trek being NCC-1701/1 or, the assigned ships registry followed by a / and a number.

I'd expect that the lowest ECV or any other registry in the Orvilleverse to be 100.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note how the existing answer has given a slightly different interpretation that is backed up by quotes and sources from the show; if you want to suggest that answer is incorrect you should provide equivalent evidence for your hypothesis.  A lot of this is supposition or not really relevant; please concentrate on answering the question that was asked.  You might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].